# custom user model and many to many permissions authentication and authorization django

Tags: django, authentication, authorization, many-to-many

I have a custom user model that I am building in Django. I'm pretty clear on how its going to work.

I though have an interesting permisions scheme.

I am trying to confrim if my thought process is correct.

Each user can be part of many venues. Of each venue a user is a part of they may have a different permission.

I have my user table and then I have a permissions table

the permissions table is of the following:

```
 pk
venueID
UserID
isclient
isvenueviewer
isvenueeventplanner
isvenueadmin
issuitsviewer
issuitssuperuser
```

the venue id can be null meaning that no all users will have venues attached to them.

my thought is that a user first gets authenticated by the user table then that user object is checked by the permissions table for what permissions that user has. Of those permissions the one needed for the current view to be authorized is filtered through. And see if valid.

am I spot on?

Thank you hugs and kisses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after research all i need to do is set up a many to many relation on the STuser table and we are set. Shown below.

```
class Permissions(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    isclient = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isvenueviewer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isvenueeventplanner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isvenueadministrator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    issuitsviewer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    issuitsadministrator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    issuitssuperuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class STUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    companyname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    userphoto = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    signupvaildatestring = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    jobtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permissions)
    # password field function is provided by AbstractBaseUser

    #objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
```